# How to sanitse information in RSS XML

Tags: php, xml, rss

I've created an RSS PHP Script which pulls information directly from a database so that I can pull and display the information on a WordPress website. The issue I am having is the XML is showing some errors

```
error on line xxx at column xxx: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
```

I've tried using sanitisation, and preg/str replace but no luck. PHP 7.3.8 running Linux and MySQL 5 and Apache 2.

```php
<?php
    // Create connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("ip", "username", "password");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Database connection failed!: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database.table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rss version='2.0'>
<channel>
<title>My Title</title>
<link>/</link>
<description>Description about the RSS Feed.</description>
<language>en-us</language>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $rowid = $row['id'];
        $id = $row['buyer_id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $message = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $row['message']);
        $message = str_replace('\'', '"', $message);
        $update = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', $row['update']);
        $update = str_replace('\'', '"', $update);
        $url = $row['url'];
        $created_at = $row['created_at'];
        $updated_at = $row['updated_at'];
        echo "<item>
<title>$title</title>
<link>$url</link>
<description>$message</description>
<update>$update</update>
<pubDate>$created_at</pubDate>
</item>";
    }
    echo "</channel>
</rss>";
?>
```

I get this error https://i.imgur.com/cnQ8pjb.png which seems to be referencing an & sign which should be getting replaced. https://i.imgur.com/PBsPjcn.png

Please can you assist?

Comment: If you generate XML as text use `htmlspecialchars()`. Or use an XML API like XMLWriter or DOM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed this myself, using the below in the HTML section.

```html
<title><![CDATA[$title]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[$message]]></description>
<update><![CDATA[$update]]></update>
```